# combine items of list

Tags: java, linked-list

Hi I have a list with lets say these items {30 50 5 60 90 5 80} what I want to do is for example combine the 3rd and 4th element together and have {30 50 65 90 5 80}

Could you tell me how would I do that? I am using the java linked list class.

Comment: Is this homework? If so, you should tag it as such

Comment: it is not, I'm trying to make something with a list and I can't remember how to merge two elements in a list

Comment: I have studied linked lists last year in college and now I just can't seem to remember them easily, what I've done is make the list and I know how to remove items from it

Comment: Please see: [Stack Overflow is not your personal research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/172496). What may be confusing you is that [Stack Overflow is not like all those other sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128554/172496)

Comment: I am actually not confused (no matter how hard it is to grasp), I just could not remember something from my last year of college and despite the research I did and the documentation I found in the Java site I could not understand how to use a Linked List in that particularly way, so I took the liberty to use a site which exists to offer answers to given questions and since I had already done my research instead of making a really generic question like "how are lists used" I asked only how to do the specific thing I needed to be done

Comment: and when I had the answer I would reseach alone in how it worked so I would not trouble more people

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
        list.add(30);
        list.add(50);
        list.add(5);
        list.add(60);
        list.add(90);
        list.add(5);
        list.add(80);
        System.out.println(list);
        combine(list, 2, 3);
        System.out.println(list);
    }
    public static void combine(List<Integer> list, int indexA, int indexB) {
        Integer a = list.get(indexA);
        Integer b = list.get(indexB);
        list.remove(indexB); // [30, 50, 5, 90, 5, 80]
        list.add(indexA, a + b); // [30, 50, 65, 5, 90, 5, 80]
        list.remove(indexB); // [30, 50, 65, 90, 5, 80]
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
[30, 50, 5, 60, 90, 5, 80]
[30, 50, 65, 90, 5, 80]
```

You need check nulls values for avoid `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 0):

Read the API documentation for LinkedList. There isn't a "combine" method, but there is a method to remove the element at a given index, and an method to insert an element anywhere in the list.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html

Answer (score 0):

I'd loop through your linked list (start at the head node).  I'm guessing there is a nextNode property on each LinkedList object that allows your iterator to work.  When you get to index 2 (with value 5), find the nextnode of index 2 (with value 60), and add that value to index 2 (with value 5 making it 65).  Then find the nextNode of index 3 (with value 60) which points to the node with value 90 (call this newNextNode) and reset the nextNode property of index 2 (with value 5) to that node.

Answer (score 0):

Add the two values in the current links, remove the two links and add a new one in their place.  The API for that is at: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html  Use the *remove* and *add* methods.

Answer (score 0):

Linked list does not provide the methods for performing operations over the list, it only manages the list. The only way to do this for you would be to retrieve the elements from the said locations and add them up and then remove the said elements from the list and then insert  the new item using index.