# Combining overlapping circles in a list in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, geometry, overlapping

This is my first time posting on here, so I apologize if I left out information or provided too much, or otherwise messed up. Please let me know if I did.

So I have a list of circles, many of which are likely to overlap.
I am detecting overlap via (Nose is my class that specifies the size(radius) and position of a circle):

```
public boolean isSame(Nose other)
{
    // if the difference between their X and Y positions are both
    // less than half the combined sizes...
    if (Math.abs(other.x - x) < (other.size + size) &&
        Math.abs(other.y - y) < (other.size + size) )
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

I believe this should return true if the circles are close, but not necessarily overlapping. This is what I want for my application (for those wanting true overlap, the top answer of this will help with that:) 
[How to detect overlapping circles and fill color accordingly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170901/how-to-detect-overlapping-circles-and-fill-color-accordingly)

Given this "overlap" detection, I am trying to combine "overlapping" circles in the list with the following code (noses is a ListArray):

```
for (int i = 0; i < noses.size(); i++)
{
    //for each nose after the current one, check for redundant noses
    for (int j = i+1; j < noses.size(); j++)
    {
        Nose noseI = noses.get(i);
        Nose noseJ = noses.get(j);
        if (noseI.isSame(noseJ))
        {
            noses.set(i, new Nose((noseI.x + noseJ.x),
                                  (noseI.y + noseJ.y),
                                  (noseI.size + noseJ.size)));
            noses.remove(j);
            j--; // decrement back to check the nose that is NOW at that place.
        }
    }
    Nose noseI = noses.get(i).getBig();
    //Add noses[i] to the image being returned
    canvas.drawCircle((float)(noseI.x), (float)(noseI.y), (float)(noseI.size), paint);
}
```

I believe that this method of looping through to find like-elements and combining them should be working, because the following code works correctly (modified from [combine items of list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10368286/combine-items-of-list)):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
  list.add(10);
  list.add(80);
  list.add(5);
  list.add(30);
  list.add(13);
  list.add(18);
  list.add(36);
  System.out.println(list);

  for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
  {
     for (int j = i + 1; j < list.size(); j++)
     {
        if (Math.abs(list.get(i) - list.get(j)) < 10)
        {
           Integer a = list.get(i);
           Integer b = list.get(j);
           list.set(i, (a + b) / 2);
           list.remove(j);
           j--;
        }
     }
  }

  System.out.println(list);
}
```

which gives me output of:

```
[10, 80, 5, 30, 13, 18, 36]
[14, 80, 33]
```

However, my actual application consistently has overlapping circles drawn on it. I'm really stumped as to why, as I've checked the combination loops with simple integers, and I'm fairly certain my overlapping detection shouldn't even have circles that are **near** each other, and so should certainly not have any overlapping.

Comment: yuor condition for overlapping circles is wrong. two circles are overlapping if the distance between both centrs is samller than the sum of radii. ditance is measured by sqaure root of((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2)

Comment: First, the condition for overlapping circles ended up not being the problem. True, it was not detecting circle overlap, but rather square overlap, but as stated, that's acceptable for my application.

The problem ended up being with the combining a list of items. When I added a random 30,000 numbers to my list [3rd code block], I found the resulting list **would** have numbers within 10 of eachother (which it should not). I found that by simply running that algorithm 2 or 3 times (at 30k numbers, 3 iterations is all it took) would give me a correct list.

Comment: Oh! The solution I found of just doing multiple iterations feels like a hack; it's not provably correct. If someone could figure out _why_ one iteration has "overlapping" values still in it, and possibly what a correct solution would be (that doesn't just resort to running iterations until it works), I would accept such an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The condition to overlap may computed as follow:

```
public boolean isSame(Nose other) {
   double dx       = other.x - x;
   double dy       = other.y - y;
   double distance = Math.sqrt( dx*dx + dy*dy );
   return distance < Math.max( size, other.size );
}
```

The naming is important `isSame` is not meaningful, I suggest `overlaps` in place.

Comment: But am I correct in my assumption that my isSame will return true if the two circles are "close" to each other? This is the functionality I want (also, isSame, as in, "do the two circles represent the same actual nose"?). Also, I'm trying to do as many approximations as possible to help with speed up, and so I'd prefer to avoid expensive operations like square root.
If my isSame _doesn't_ do what I think it does, that could explain my problem. Otherwise, I'm still wondering why my final list has overlapping circles.

Comment: When you say "overlaps" did you think "totally at the same place"? i.e. both center very closed from each other?

Comment: No. The application is facial detection, and the circles are being drawn over the noses of the faces that are found, so two circles are "overlapping" of they're close enough that they're really representing the same face. So they need not actually overlap to be considered "overlapping" for my purposes. So (()), ()() would both be "overlapping", but ()   () [sufficiently separated] would not.